# In Graphql what is the best practice for resolving expensive queries?

Tags: graphql

What is the best practice for resolving expensive nested queries? For example, if you have several 1:many layers, even with paging you may end up with 1:50 * 1:50 * 1:50 = 125,000 results.

Is there a limit where you might throw an error?

Here's an example where you might have organization: 50 users, user: 50 photos.

```
{
  viewer {
    organization {
      users {
        edges {
          node {
            photos
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 'dataloader n+1'

Comment: Thanks @xadm. Followup question - is there a limit to using data loader? Data loader helps batch the requests, but at some point the volume of data might not be too tenable.

Comment: no strict advices ... implementation related ... use lower limits? look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53469612/6124657 or other public API limiting scenarios